# Docker on machine using a ramdisk doesn't work

Tags: docker, ramdisk

My machine that boots on a ramdisk cannot start a docker container.

For example, running `hello-world` results in

```
$ docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:109: jailing process inside rootfs caused \\\"pivot_root invalid argument\\\"\"": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Unfortunately, the `DOCKER_RAMDISK=true` variable does not seem to have an effect. I set it before restarting the docker service with `systemctl restart docker` but with no effect.
(I'm on Debian Buster)

Comment: Did you `export DOCKER_RAMDISK`?

Comment: yes I did, strangely calling `DOCKER_RAMDISK=true dockerd &` works however

Answer (score 6):

If the setting applies to `dockerd`, then try configuring this in systemd (should just be able to copy/paste the following into a root shell):

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
cat >/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-ramdisk.conf <<EOF
[Service]
Environment=DOCKER_RAMDISK=true
EOF
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: I don't have an environment to test this in, but looking at the code it appears you are correct in seeing this as a `dockerd` rather than `docker` setting. Let me know if you get this to work and I'll look into sending a documentation PR.